# Getting Empty SMS body

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sms

Hi trying to send SMS with android using below code.

```
 public static void sendsmsstd(String number, String message, Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        intent.putExtra("address", number);
        intent.putExtra("sms-body", message);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Many sites have suggested it , but when code runs and SMS app opens, it choose right contact to send message but message body is always empty.

What else can be done to fix it. I m missing some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using sms-body. Change that to sms_body and that should fix it.